# mutate and case_when assigns wrong value

Tags: r, dplyr

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out what is wrong with this code. When `frameNum` is 1-63, the code assigns `anticipatory`, but everything else is assigned as `NA`.

```
total_s2_data <- total_s2_data %>%
  mutate(frame_cat = case_when(
    frameNum == c(1:63, 120:193, 488:543, 580:625) ~ "anticipatory",
    frameNum == c(64:69, 194:219, 544:563, 626:653) ~ "phone",
    frameNum == c(70:193, 220:297, 564:625, 654:725) ~ "carryover",
    TRUE ~ NA)
  )
```

Here's code to be able to replicate:

```
frameNum<- c(1:725)
total_s2_data <- as.data.frame(frameNum)
```

Comment: Your example code and data gives an error: "Error: must be a character vector, not a logical vector".

Comment: I suspect you want `%in%` not `==`. Like `1:10 %in% 1:3` vs `1:10 == 1:3`

Comment: Also `NA_character_` instead of `NA`

Comment: Or to show the problem more clearly, compare `10:1 %in% 1:3` vs `10:1 == 1:3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*1.* `==` needs to be replaced by `%in%`, and

*2.* `NA` needs to be replaced by `NA_character_`.

The error `"Error: must be a character vector, not a logical vector"` is due to 2nd.

```
total_s2_data <- total_s2_data %>%
  mutate(frame_cat = case_when(
    frameNum %in% c(1:63, 120:193, 488:543, 580:625) ~ "anticipatory",
    frameNum %in% c(64:69, 194:219, 544:563, 626:653) ~ "phone",
    frameNum %in% c(70:193, 220:297, 564:625, 654:725) ~ "carryover",
    TRUE ~ NA_character_)
  )

 head(total_s2_data)
#   frameNum    frame_cat
#1        1 anticipatory
#2        2 anticipatory
#3        3 anticipatory
#4        4 anticipatory
#5        5 anticipatory
#6        6 anticipatory
```